# Direct jump to specific page in angular datatable

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-datatables

I am Using an angular datatable in one of the application and in one of the condition I want to jump to specific page in the table.
Could you please help me out?
Code details:

```
    user.ts and user .html       
        user.ts
    //defined dt option as any
    dtOptions: any = {};



    NgOnint(){
          this.dtOptions = {
        pagingType:'simple_numbers',
        language: { 
          search: '',
          searchPlaceholder: 'Search',
          lengthMenu: 'Show _MENU_ Entries',

         paginate: {
            next: '&#10095;',
            previous: '&#10094;'  
          }
        },
        pageLength:5,
        paging :true,
        lengthChange: true,
        lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
       ]

              user.html
           <table  id="datatable"
            datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table table-border table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="TableHeader">
                      <th class="TableHeaderth" #subId id="subId">USERID</th>
                      <th class="TableHeaderth">USERGROUP</th>
                      <th class="TableHeaderth">USER FIRST NAME</th>
                       <th class="TableHeaderth">USER MIDDLE NAME</th>
                       <th class="TableHeaderth">USER LAST NAME</th>
                       <th class="TableHeaderth">USER FULL NAME</th>
                       <th class="TableHeaderth">USER TYPE</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="tbody">
                  <tr *ngFor="let person of persons;let i = index">
                <td class="tabletdclientid">{{person.subscriberId}}</td>
                <td class="tabletdclientname">{{person.subscriberName}}</td>
                <td class="tabletdshrtname" id="alignshrtname"><span class={{person.Priority}}>{{person.client.clientName}}</span></td>  
                <td class="tabletd">{{person.subscriberDesc}}</td>
                <td class="tabletdclientid">{{person.subscriberRemarks}}</td>
                <td class="tabletd">{{person.subscriberAuthAttribute}}</td>
                <td class="tabletd">{{person.subscriberIsActive}}</td>
                  </tr> 
                </t body>
                </table>
```

I have a button and on click of the button method Test() will be called and data table records should jump to a specific page.

```
     <button (click)="test()"></button>
```

Could you please let me know how to jump to specific page?

Comment: Just to understand what you are trying to achieve, do you want to navigate to a new page with the user data when button is clicked?

Comment: Hi thank you for replying                                                                                    
 .nope .requirement is to jump to Nth page in the datatable . like if there are 12 pages in the datatable and if i click on the button records in the 12th page of datatable should be displayed.

Comment: the exact solution is to use draw() method of data table.

Comment: this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
    dtInstance.page(pagenumber).draw(false);
  });